# Hive connection pooling mechanism

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, connection, pool

I am using hive 2.1.0 version.
I have a jdbc connection from java side to connect to hive server2. But now i need to create a jdbc connection once and create a datasource pool so that the multiple queries do not create a new connection everytime and use the pooling mechanism instead. Is there any way to implement the pooling mechanism in hive?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi @nitish_shah, did you manage to solve this problem?
I also have the same use case, can you please share your solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: @AmanSinghal i switched to Spark-SQL with Hive support and executed queries using enableHiveSupport() in Spark Session.

Comment: Okay @nitish_shah, my application is standalone java microservice and has nothing to do with spark, anyway thanks for your help.